# ASP.NET Web Forms - Response.Redirect to SEO friendly URL

Tags: asp.net, seo, friendly-url, response.redirect

We have a stockists page where we can filter by product and/or fragrance with the following URL

```
/products/stockists?product=all&fragrance=all
```

And we are looking to update this to a friendly URL as follows

```
/products/stockists/all/all
```

To do this, we have setup a button click as follows

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var product = this.Product.SelectedValue;
    var fragrance = this.Fragance.SelectedValue;
    base.Response.Redirect("~/products/stockists/" + product + "/" + fragrance);
}
```

And we have setup the following URL rewrite

```
<rule name="Stockists Rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^products/stockists/(.*)/(.*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/products/stockists.aspx?product={R:1}&amp;fragrance={R:2}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

So if I go to /products/stockists and click the submit button, it correctly goes to the friendly URL **/products/stockists/all/all**

If I then click the submit button again, it goes back to the unfriendly URL **/products/stockists?product=all&fragrance=all**

Any ideas as to why this might be happening would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the user control Page_Load event

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (!this.Page.IsPostBack) {
    if (base.Request.QueryString["store"] != null) {
      this.FindStore();
    }
    else if (base.Request.QueryString["product"] != null) {
        var fragrance = base.Request.QueryString["fragrance"].Replace("+", " ").Replace("$", "&");
        var product = base.Request.QueryString["product"].Replace("+", " ");

        this.DropDownList1.SelectedValue = fragrance;
        this.DropDownList2.SelectedValue = product;

        this.DisplayAll();
    } else {
        this.DisplayAll();
    }
  }
}
```

Web.config redirects and rewrites. Not 100% sure everything is in the right order but all other rewrites/redirects work as expected.

```
<rewrite>
  <rewriteMaps>
    <rewriteMap name="Redirects">
      <add key="/fragrances.aspx" value="/products/company-fragrances.aspx" />
      <add key="/products/concentrated-disinfectants.aspx" value="/products/company-products.aspx" />
      <add key="/products/antibacterial-sprays.aspx" value="/products/company-products/antibacterial-sprays.aspx" />
      <add key="/products/professional-disinfectants.aspx" value="/products/company-products/professional-disinfectants.aspx" />
      <add key="/company-uses.aspx" value="/products/company-uses.aspx" />
      <add key="/stockists.aspx" value="/products/stockists.aspx" />
      <add key="/about-company.aspx" value="/in-the-know/about-company.aspx" />
      <add key="/news.aspx" value="/in-the-know/news.aspx" />
      <add key="/company-community.aspx" value="/in-the-know/company-community.aspx" />
      <add key="/faqs.aspx" value="/in-the-know/faqs.aspx" />
      <add key="/contact-us.aspx" value="/in-the-know/contact-us.aspx" />
      <add key="/bacteria--viruses/what-are-bacteria.aspx" value="/company-at-home/bacteria--viruses/what-are-bacteria.aspx" />
      <add key="/bacteria--viruses/what-are-viruses.aspx" value="/company-at-home/bacteria--viruses/what-are-viruses.aspx" />
      <add key="/bacteria--viruses/prevention-of-infection.aspx" value="/company-at-home/bacteria--viruses/prevention-of-infection.aspx" />
      <add key="/room-explorer.aspx" value="/company-at-home/room-explorer.aspx" />
      <add key="/competitions/win-a-molly-maid-cleaner-for-a-year!.aspx" value="/competitions/win-a-molly-maid-cleaner-for-a-year.aspx" />
      <add key="/stockists.aspx?store=Tesco" value="/products/stockists/tesco.aspx" />
      <add key="/stockists.aspx?store=Sainsbury%27s" value="/products/stockists/sainsburys.aspx" />
      <add key="/stockists.aspx?store=Asda" value="/products/stockists/asda.aspx" />
      <add key="/stockists.aspx?store=Morrisons" value="/products/stockists/morrisons.aspx" />
      <add key="/stockists.aspx?store=Savers" value="/products/stockists/savers.aspx" />
      <add key="/stockists.aspx?store=Wilkinson%27s" value="/products/stockists/wilkinsons.aspx" />
    </rewriteMap>
  </rewriteMaps>
  <rules>
    <clear />

    <rule name="Redirect Rule" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{Redirects:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="False" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>

    <rule name="Redirect Fragrances" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^fragrances/(.*)" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="/products/company-fragrances/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>

    <rule name="Redirect company Uses" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^company-uses/(.*)" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="/products/company-uses/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>

    <rule name="Redirect News" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^news/(.*)" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="in-the-know/news/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>

    <rule name="Redirect company Community" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^company-community/(.*)" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="in-the-know/company-community/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>

    <rule name="Canonical home page" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(home|home\.aspx|default|default\.aspx)$" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="/" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>

    <rule name="Trim aspx for directory URLs" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)\.aspx$" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/umbraco/" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="\.axd$" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}/" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>

    <rule name="Lower Case Rule" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*[A-Z].*" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/umbraco/" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^.*\.(axd|asmx|css|js|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|mp3)$" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="/Base" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="cdv=1" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="\.axd$" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{URL}}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>

    <rule name="Remove trailing slash" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)/$" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/umbraco/" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^.*\.(asp|aspx|axd|asmx|css|js|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|mp3)$" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="/Base" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="cdv=1" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="\.axd$" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
    </rule>

    <rule name="Stockists Rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^products/stockists/(.*)/(.*)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/products/stockists.aspx?product={R:1}&amp;fragrance={R:2}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>

  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: It works fine for me. Could be something else is going on in the form. Could you post the code for your view as well?